# Unable to run phpunit since upgrade to Symfony 2.8/3.0

Tags: symfony

Since upgrading to Symfony 2.8, I get the following error when I run `phpunit` in the Symfony root:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler' not found in /var/www/foo/symfony/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/DeprecationErrorHandler.php on line 40
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:138
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:657
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:789
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:873
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:416
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:355
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
PHP  11. Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\DeprecationErrorHandler::Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\{closure}() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:92

THE ERROR HANDLER HAS CHANGED!
```

This also occurs under Symfony 3.0. Should I now be running phpunit in a different manner?

Comment: Do a composer require phpunit/phpunit folowed by vendor/bin/phpunit and see what happens.  Things work for me under S3.  Do need to make sure your version of phpunit matches your php version.  But the error handler class is definitely there for phpunit 3.x and 4.x.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that phpunit/phpunit is required in Symfony 3.0? The sample composer.json only features symfony/phpunit-bridge: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.0/composer.json

Comment: It's not so much required as it that by installing via composer, you ensure you have the correct version of phpunit for each project.  Try it.  If it works then you know that you need to update your global install.  Or just stop using the global.

Comment: For those of you running: "phpunit -c app" symfony3 only requires the command: "phpunit". (You're welcome).

Comment: I got this error, too. I´m using phpunit from composer and also the phpunit bridge. Clearing  Cache etc. -> same result. I´m using 2.8 - did you solved this problem already?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem using Symfony 2.8.

Just update your local install of phpunit.

Run this.

```
phpunit --self-update
```

That should do it.

I was running phpunit version 4.7.*, but Symfony wanted to see phpunit 5.1.3.

You should clear the app/cache/test directory.

You could also make your global phpunit symlink to the one provided by Symfony located in vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit

Update: I'm not sure what this error is referring to, I still get it, but seems to occur when I have a problem with a test. At the least, it's a confusing message.